# Tips on how to read last 'word' in a character array in C

Tags: c, scanf, stdio, fgets

Just looking to be pointed in the right direction:

Have standard input to a C program, I've taken each line in at a time and storing in a char[].

Now that I have the char[], how do I take the last word (just assuming separated by a space) and then convert to lowercase?

I've tried this but it just hangs the program:

```
while (sscanf(line, "%s", word) == 1)
    printf("%s\n", word);
```

Taken what was suggested and came up with this, is there a more efficient way of doing this?

```
char* last = strrchr(line, ' ')+1;

while (*last != '\0'){   
    *last = tolower(*last);
    putchar((int)*last);
    last++;
}
```

Comment: Is the `;` at the end of the `while` on purpose ? Because that will make a loop as long as you feed input... maybe pressing Ctrl-D will make it stop, but I guess that's not what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I had to do this, I'd probably start with `strrchr`. That should get you the beginning of the last word. From there it's a simple matter of walking through characters and converting to lower case. Oh, there is the minor detail that you'd have to delete any trailing space characters first.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited my question with the code I've made, is this the best way of doing this?

Comment: +1. strrchr is *the* precise answer. Also mention of minor detail was nice. @Igor K: I am not a veteran either, but what I have seen is the following: If an answer helps you, then the custom is to upvote (and for askers, accept) the answer, not to to update the question.

Comment: @ArunSaha, I understand, I'll accept once I hear from other members this is the best way of doing this. Since I'm very inexperienced at C, it would be unwise to accept this answer over say @Installer if @Installer turned out to be the most popular choice by others.

Comment: strrchr is not "the" precise answer, see char *s = " foo bar ";

Comment: @user411313: You are right, and I think that's the reason the answer mentioned: "Oh, there is the minor detail that you'd have to delete any trailing space characters first."

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your code is that it will repeatedly read the first word of the sentence into *word*. It will not move to the next word each time you call it. So if you have this as your code:

```
char * line = "this is a line of text";
```

Then every single time sscanf is called, it will load "this" into *word*. And since it read 1 word each time, sscanf will *always* return 1.

Answer (score 0):

'strtok' will split the input string based on certain delimitors, in your case the delimitor would be a space, thus it will return an array of "words" and you would simply take the last one.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/

One could illustrate many different methods of performing this operation and then determine which one contained the best performance and useability characteristics, or the advantages and disadvantages of each, I simply wanted to illustrate what I mentioned above with a code snippet.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    char line[] = "This is a sentence with a last WoRd ";

    char *lastWord = NULL;
    char *token = strtok(line, " ");
    while (token != NULL)
    {
        lastWord = token;
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");      
    }

    while (*lastWord)
    {
        printf("%c", tolower(*lastWord++));
    }

    _getch();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help:

```
char dest[10], source [] = "blah blah blah!" ;
int sum = 0 , index =0 ;
while(sscanf(source+(sum+=index),"%s%n",dest,&index)!=-1);
printf("%s\n",dest) ;
```